# How to save foreign key values from a form to a django database?

Tags: django, forms, view

I'm trying to save a django from a form into a database. The problem is in foreign key. As a result, entries in the database are all available except foreign key.

django 2.2, python3.

models.py:

```
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, default=None,
                                   verbose_name='Отчество')
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Пол')
    age = models.ForeignKey(Age_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Возраст. кат-ия')
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Турнир')
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Дивизион')
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, blank=True, null=True, default=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Дисциплина')

views.py:
def sportsman(request):
    documents = Document.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    form = SportsmenForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        data = form.cleaned_data
        print(form.cleaned_data['email'])
        form.save(commit=True)
        new_form = form.save()
    return render(request, 'sportsman/sportsman.html', locals())

forms.py:
class SportsmenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sportsman
        exclude = ['created', 'updated']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link up other models that are connected to your main form using [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: I tried to do this, but as a result, the entered and selected data is written to the database, but not quite correctly. The ForeignKey writes down only those values that have id = 1. On the HTML form, the select correctly gives me a list of all the ForeignKey, but for some reason, writing to the database always goes by id = 1.